# Set dynamic download path to django

Tags: python, django, dynamic, download

How i can set a dynamic download path to django by change this part:

> (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'folder/path/file.pdf')

```
    with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'folder/path/file.pdf'), 'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=invoice.pdf'
    return response
```

to something like this:

> (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, FUNCTION_RETURN_THE_PATH)

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, FUNCTION_RETURN_THE_PATH), 'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=invoice.pdf'
    return response
```

If a use function i get many errors, because it expects a string variable in this place and not a function.

in my html there is a for that show all the model to user

```
{% for printforme in print_user_charges %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ printforme.invoice_number }}</td>
              <td>{{ printforme.price }} €</td>
              <td>{{  printforme.reason }}</td>
              <td>{{ printforme.customer }} {{ printforme.customer.surname }}</td>
              <td>{{ printforme.charge_date }}</td>
              <td>  <a href="{% url 'download_pdf' printforme.upload_pdf.id %}"> Download </a></td>
```

the download link drives into a view:

```
def DownloadPdf(request, charge_id):

with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, get_file_path), 'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=invoice.pdf'
    return response
```

I store pdf, base to the user id like this:

```
def invoice_path_base_to_usersid(instance, filename):
return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.customer.id, filename)
```

So i store pdfs to media/user_{id}/filename.pdf

I want user to downlaod a specific pdf file when he click on the currect item.
But i dont know how to use the user id and put it inside the open to download the currect one pdf that user want.

Comment: This is very unclear. What does your function do? Does it return a string? Are you actually calling it anywhere?

Comment: I was not asking for a solution to my whole project. I just wonter if there is any way to pass other things than a direct string path in the open(...) function.

Comment: Yes of course. If you have a function that returns a string, and you call it there, Python won't know the difference. You are obviously not doing one of those things there, but without seeing real code we can't know what.

Comment: I edit my question, so it helps you understand, sorry for the misunderstood information that i provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution, i post it here to help anyone that struggles with that things.

My main problem it was that i was try to get an instance and i do not pass it into any variable before i try to load the file.

I change the open method to, i found the last one more clear.

```
def DownloadPdf(request, charges_id):

try:
    invoice = Charge.objects.get(pk=charges_id)
except Charge.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404

response = HttpResponse(File(invoice.upload_pdf), content_type="application/pdf")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
return response
```

So the answer is, if you want a dynamicaly download path in django you have to query your model and put the output in a variable.

After that, by calling this variable, in that way:

> variable.field_of_model

you can refer to any field of that record and use it as you want

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function.

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, get_file_path()), 'rb') as fh:
```

Comment: I do it and it gives me the error:

FileDescriptor' object is not callable